# Taking ownership of a &String without copying

Tags: rust, ownership

### Context

Link: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=9a9ffa99023735f4fbedec09e1c7ac55

Here's a contrived repro of what I'm running into

```rust
fn main() {
   let mut s = String::from("Hello World");
   example(&mut s);
}

fn example(s: &mut str) -> Option<String> {
    other_func(Some(s.to_owned()))
    // other random mutable stuff happens
}

fn other_func(s: Option<String>) {
    match s {
        Some(ref s) => other_func2(*s),
        None => panic!()
    }
}

fn other_func2(s: String) {
    println!("{}", &s)
}
```

and the error

```
   Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
error[E0507]: cannot move out of `*s` which is behind a shared reference
  --> src/main.rs:12:36
   |
12 |         Some(ref s) => other_func2(*s),
   |                                    ^^ move occurs because `*s` has type `String`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

### Question

In the following code, why can't I deference the `&String` without having to do some sort of clone/copy? i.e. this doesn't work

```
fn other_func(s: Option<String>) {
    match s {
        Some(ref s) => other_func2(*s),
        None => panic!()
    }
}
```

but it works if I replace `*s` with `s.to_owned()/s.to_string()/s.clone()`

As an aside, I understand this can probably be solved by refactoring to use `&str`, but I'm specifically interested in turning `&String -> String`

Comment: simply remove the `ref` from `ref s` and it should work (and remove the `*` from `*s`)

Comment: @kmdreko yeah that works as I expected...I'm guessing there's something different about my code that breaks this.

edit: facepalm...it was inside a loop and since I needed to use that same value multiple times, it makes sense that the second iteration would fail. So it's not that I can't deference `&String`, but that I was being dumb lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why would the compiler allow you to?

`s` is `&String`. And you cannot get a `String` from a `&String` without cloning. That's obvious.

And the fact that it was created from an owned `String`? The compiler doesn't care, and it is right. This is not different from the following code:

```rust
let s: String = ...;
let r: &String = ...;
let s2: String = *r; // Error
```

Which is in turn not different from the following code, for instance, as far as the compiler is concerned:

```rust
let r: &String = ...;
let s: String = *s;
```

And we no longer have an owned string at the beginning. In general, the compiler doesn't track data flow. And rightfully so - when it type-checks the move it doesn't even can confirm that this reference isn't aliased. Or that the owned value is not used anymore. References are just references, they give you no right to drop the value.

Changing that will not be feasible in the general case (for example, the compiler will have to track data flow across function calls), and will require some form of manual annotation to say "this value is mine". And you already have such annotation - use an owned value, `String`, instead of `&String`: this is exactly what it's about.